# The server tag is not well formed for anchor tag in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

Why

```
 <a id="link" runat="server" href="javascript:downloadFile('<%#Eval("TempKey") %>')"><%#Eval("ShortFileName") %></a>
```

is giving me `The server tag is not well formed` exception in my asp.net application?

What' is wrong ? If I remove `runat="server"`, then it is OK . But I need to handle it (which is inside a gridview) from the code behind .

Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 3):

You get `The server tag is not well formed` error because you are using double quotes within double quotes making `attribute-name="value"` kind of syntax going hay-wire. It would be parsed by ASP.NET compiler as something like

```
href="javascript:downloadFile('<%#Eval(" TempKey ") %>')">
```

TempKey would appear as separate attribute with no value etc.
When you remove server tags, ASP.NET would not parse the html element syntax it but rather emit it as it is (its invalid html as well as but browsers are far more forgiving).

You should probably try it within single quotes such as

```
href='javascript:downloadFile("<%#Eval("TempKey") %>")'
```

**EDIT**
Above would still produce problematic html as there would be un-escaped double quote in href value. So try this:

```
href='javascript:downloadFile(&quot;<%#Eval("TempKey") %>&quot;)'
```

**EDIT**
It appears that data binding expression is not getting evaluated in above. Please try below expression which uses `Eval` overload for formatting

```
href='<%# Eval("TempKey", "javascript:downloadFile(&quot;{0}&quot;)") %>'
```

**EDIT**
Yet another alternative is to use some code-behind method - for example,

```
href='<%# GetFileLink(Container.DataItem) %>)'
```

And in code-behind

```
protected string GetFileLink(object dataItem)
{
   return string.Format("javascript:downloadFile('{0}');", 
           DataBinder.Eval(dataItem, "TempKey")); 
}
```

Comment: isn't there a need to concat the variable to the string?

Comment: @Vogel612, did not understand - `Eval` expression is a server side code that would substitute characters within java-script string - where do you nee concat?

Comment: @VinayC - > Now the error is solved. but it does not show correctly.
here is my codes.
      **<a id="link" runat="server" href='javascript:downloadFile("<%#Eval("TempKey") %>")'><%#Eval("ShortFileName") %></a>**



But it shows like **")" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl00_gvAttachment_ctl02_link">aaa.docx**

It should only show **aaa.docx**

Comment: @kevin, need to escape double quotes in html attribute value i.e. `href='javascript:downloadFile(&quot;<%#Eval("TempKey") %>&quot;)'`. Also edited the answer.

Comment: @VinayC, still the same. when I view the source I got this `<a href="javascript:downloadFile("<%#Eval("TempKey") %>")" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl00_gvAttachment_aaa">201211260012H.docx</a>` but it's still showing in UI as `")" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl00_gvAttachment_aaa">201211260012H.docx`

Comment: @Kevin, if source says `"javascript:downloadFile("<%#Eval("TempKey") %>")"` then its an issue - its not evaluating data-binding expression (leaving un-escaped double quotes within). Please try yet another alternative - `href='<%# Eval("TempKey", "javascript:downloadFile(&quot;{0}&quot;)") %>'` (I have also edited the answer with the same)

Comment: @Kevin, beats me! Is it a parser error? Perhaps, explicit call to databinder may help - `href='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TempKey", "javascript:downloadFile(&quot;{0}&quot;)") %>'`

Comment: @VinayC, Sorry to bother you again. it's still showing the error. The source is `<a runat="server" id="ii" href='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TempKey", "javascript:downloadFile(&quot;{0}&quot;)") %>'><%#Eval("FileName") %></a>
`

Comment: @kevin, no idea... suggest that you try a code-behind method to form the URL (see my edit).

Answer (score 3):

In my grid view i have used Linkbutton and applied following code on **OnClientClick**.

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Print">
    <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtn_prntmenu" runat="server" CssClass="mlinks" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID")%>' CommandName="Print" Text="Print" OnClientClick='<%#Eval("ID","javascript:downloadFile(\"{0}\");")%>'></asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>

</asp:TemplateField>
```

Similarly you can do with you `<a>` element on `href`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But when I implement it, i need to click twice.

Comment: `<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLinkDoc" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("FileName") %>' NavigateUrl='<%= GenerateURL(<%#Eval("Key") %>) %>' />`

I pass the url from the code behind inside GenerateURL method.
`protected string GenerateURL(string tempKey)
        {
            return ResolveUrl("~//Common/Downloader.ashx") + "?Key=" + tempKey.ToString() ;
        }`

Answer (score 2):

> What' is wrong ?

The ASP.NET parser messes with the nested double quotes.
I just realize it does not seem to happen with VS2012 anymore.

> If I remove runat="server", then it is OK . But I need to handle it (which is inside a gridview) from the code behind .

If you have a class for your DataItem, you could just try casting :

```
<a id="link" runat="server" href="javascript:downloadFile('<%#((YourNamespace.YourClass)Container.DataItem).TempKey%>')"><%#Eval("ShortFileName") %></a>
```

Best thing to do should be to set the href in codebehind (this is a point of having a runat="server" control)

Hope this will help,

Answer (score 1):

Try following code:

```
onclick='<%# "return jsPopup('UpdateProbAct.aspx?Table=problems&Deptid=" + Eval("department") %>'
```

Comment: Sorry, can you explain it a bit more ?